# What does *= mean in Java?

Tags: java, string, int, operator-keyword

I'm going through a tutorial and I found this operator but I'm not sure what it does.

int number = Integer.parseInt(tfInput.getText());

**number *= number;**

tfResult.setText(number + "");

Thanks.

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/operators.html

Comment: Try running your code with a few values and see if you can figureit out. Or read the java tutorial

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`a *= b;` is equivalent to `a = a * b;`

You're probably (maybe?) familiar with the `+=` operator.  There is a similar operator for all the basic math functions.

- `+=`: `a += b;` is equivalent to `a = a + b;`
- `-=`: `a -= b;` is equivalent to `a = a - b;`
- `*=`: `a *= b;` is equivalent to `a = a * b;`
- `/=`: `a /= b;` is equivalent to `a = a / b;`
- `%=`: `a %= b;` is equivalent to `a = a % b;`

And please make note of @ruakh's comment:

> Note that a *= b evaluates a only once, whereas a = a * b evaluates it
>   twice. (That doesn't make a difference if a is just a variable or
>   field name, but if it's a more complicated expression, such as f().x
>   or f.g.x, that can matter a great deal.)

Comment: +1, but note that `a *= b` evaluates `a` only once, whereas `a = a * b` evaluates it twice. (That doesn't make a difference if `a` is just a variable or field name, but if it's a more complicated expression, such as `f().x` or `f.g.x`, that can matter a great deal.)

Comment: Thanks. I just wasn't expecting it to be arithmetic, since the tutorial is just about GUIs and changing from ints to strings and back again.

Comment: I'm not sure what tutorial you're working your way through, but there's quite a lot of arithmetic involved in GUIs usually...

Comment: _`*=`: `a *= b;` is equivalent to `a = a * b;`_ --
        Let's say we have `a *= b + c`:
        Would it be equivalent to `a = (a * b) + c` or `a = a * (b + c)`? Answer: It is equivalent to `a = a * (b +c)`